# Как скрыть элемент пока не применится нужный шрифт?

Tags: javascript, html, css, frontend

В коде ниже, во время загрузки страницы вместо "u" генерируется знак рубля "₽" с нужными стилями. "u"  здесь выступает в качестве заглушки и без нее, к сожалению никак.

```
<span class="ruble">u</span>
```

```css
.ruble {
    font-family: 'Conv_rouble' !important;
    font-weight: normal !important;
}
```

Проблема в том, что при  медленном интернете во время загрузки страницы можно увидеть эту "u" буквально на 1-2 секунды. Заказчик просит это исправить...
Подставить вместо "u" сам знак ₽ не прокатит, в этом случае шрифт 'Conv_rouble' не сработает :)
(пробел тоже).
Кучу вариантов потыкал в коде, так ниче и не работает(.

Решал похожую проблему во Vue, нужно было скрыть появление vue-переменных. Но там это легко решается через **v-cloak**. Здесь же нужно сделать тоже самое, только с **css**..

Хотелось бы решение что-то типа скрыть элемент, пока не сработает шрифт, скорее это как-то через **js** нужно сделать. Но я вообще уже не понимаю как. Если кто-то сталкивался с подобным или есть идеи, буду рад почитать)

Comment: Если шрифт загружается через css, то можно попробовать установить значение [font-display](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/f/font-display/) block. Если через link, тогда можно слушать [onload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3078584/link-element-onload) на ссылке, и скрывать/показывать u

Comment: @Anynomius , ДА!!! *font-display: block* сработало!!! СПАСИБО БОЛЬШОЕ! Я столько часов на это потратил, а Вы одним советом решили задачу! Золотой Вы человек!))

Answer (score 0):

html:

```
<span class="ruble none">u</span>
```

css:

```
.ruble{
    font-family: 'Conv_rouble' !important;
    font-weight: normal !important;
}
.none{
    display: none;
}
```

js:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   let ruble = document.getElementsByClassName('ruble')
   ruble.classList.remove("none");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

если проблемy правильно понял, это должнo помочь.

```
.rouble {
       display: inline-block;
       min-width: 1ch;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
<span id="ruble" class="ruble">u</span>
```

CSS:

```
.ruble {
    font-family: 'Conv_rouble' !important;
    font-weight: normal !important;
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

JS:

```
document.fonts.ready.then(function() {
    document.getElementById('ruble').style.visibility = 'visible';
});
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]